# the trait bound `Kitty<T>: TypeInfo` is not satisfied

Tags: pallet, storage, kitties-tutorial

I was following the substrate kitties tutorial where i needed to create a storage map where the id is mapped to the `kitty` struct which is created. But i am getting the following error.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Kitty<T>: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/mykitties/src/lib.rs:85:12
   |
85 |     #[pallet::storage]
   |               ^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `Kitty<T>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `TypeInfo`:
             &T
             &mut T
             ()
             (A, B)
             (A, B, C)
             (A, B, C, D)
             (A, B, C, D, E)
             (A, B, C, D, E, F)
           and 167 others
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `StaticTypeInfo` for `Kitty<T>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `StorageEntryMetadataBuilder` for `frame_support::pallet_prelude::StorageMap<_GeneratedPrefixForStorageKitties<T>, frame_support::Twox64Concat, <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash, Kitty<T>>`
```

This is my pallet code below(pallets/mykitties/src/lib.rs)

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

pub use pallet::*;

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::{
        dispatch::{DispatchResult, DispatchResultWithPostInfo},
        pallet_prelude::*,
        sp_runtime::traits::{Hash, Zero},
        traits::{Currency, ExistenceRequirement, Randomness},
    };
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    use sp_io::hashing::blake2_128;

    #[cfg(feature = "std")]
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

    type AccountOf<T> = <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId;
    type BalanceOf<T> =
        <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;

    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
    pub enum Gender {
        Male,
        Female,
    }

    impl Default for Gender {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Gender::Male
        }
    }

    #[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq)]
    pub struct Kitty<T: Config> {
        pub dna: [u8; 16],
        pub price: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
        pub gender: Gender,
        pub owner: AccountOf<T>,
    }

    // TODO Part II: Struct for holding Kitty information.

    // TODO Part II: Enum and implementation to handle Gender type in Kitty struct.

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types it depends on.
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: pallet_balances::Config + frame_system::Config {
        /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;

        // The Currency handler for the Kitties pallet.
        type Currency: Currency<Self::AccountId>;

        // TODO Part II: Specify the custom types for our runtime.
        type KittyRandomness: Randomness<Self::Hash, Self::BlockNumber>;

        #[pallet::constant]
        type MaxKittyOwned: Get<u32>;
    }

    // Errors.
    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        // TODO Part III
    }

    #[pallet::event]
    // #[pallet::metadata(T::AccountId = "AccountId")]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        // TODO Part III
    }

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn all_kitties_count)]
    pub(super) type AllKittiesCount<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, u64, ValueQuery>;

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn kitties)]
    /// Stores a Kitty's unique traits, owner and price.
    pub(super) type Kitties<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, T::Hash, Kitty<T>>;

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn kitties_owned)]
    pub(super) type KittiesOwned<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Twox64Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        BoundedVec<T::Hash, T::MaxKittyOwned>,
        ValueQuery,
    >;

    // TODO Part II: Remaining storage items.

    // TODO Part III: Our pallet's genesis configuration.

    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        // TODO Part III: create_kitty

        // TODO Part III: set_price

        // TODO Part III: transfer

        // TODO Part III: buy_kitty

        // TODO Part III: breed_kitty
    }

    impl<T: Config> Kitty<T> {
        pub fn gender(dna: T::Hash) -> Gender {
            if dna.as_ref()[0] % 2 == 0 {
                Gender::Male
            } else {
                Gender::Female
            }
        }
    }

    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        // TODO Part III: helper functions for dispatchable functions

        // TODO: increment_nonce, random_hash, mint, transfer_from

        fn gen_gender() -> Gender {
            let random = T::KittyRandomness::random(&b"gender"[..]).0;
            match random.as_ref()[0] % 2 {
                0 => Gender::Male,
                _ => Gender::Female,
            }
        }

        fn gen_dna() -> [u8; 16] {
            let payload = (
                T::KittyRandomness::random(&b"gender"[..]).0,
                <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number(),
            );

            payload.using_encoded(blake2_128)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code: https://github.com/dhruvja/substrate-kitties

Please can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you import https://github.com/paritytech/scale-info in your cargo? And have a use statement for it? And derive it for the struct that is complaining it needs it? Here is the canonical example pallet to reference https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/examples/basic/src/lib.rs#L282

Answer (score 5):

Add `TypeInfo` and `#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]` . Because your struct define Generic type

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct Kitty<T: Config> {
      pub dna: [u8; 16],
      pub price: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
      pub gender: Gender,
      pub owner: AccountOf<T>,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement TypeInfo Trait to Kitty's Struct like below.

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, TypeInfo)]
pub struct Kitty<T: Config> {
    pub dna: [u8; 16],
    pub price: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
    pub gender: Gender,
    pub owner: AccountOf<T>,
}
```

Comment: ```the trait bound `T: scale_info::TypeInfo` is not satisfied``` I am getting this after adding the above TypeInfo

Answer (score 0):

`#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]` annotating the struct worked for me.